# Insert from two tables to one while on duplicate just add quantity

Tags: sql, database, h2

I have three tables in H2 database having no relation with each other.

Table 1: `NETSALE:Attributes>  INVOICEDATE | PRODUCTID | QUANTITY`

Table 2: `BALANCESALE:Attributes>  INVOICEDATE | PRODUCTID | QUANTITY`

Table 3: `ANNUALSALE:Attributes>  MONTH | PRODUCTID | QUANTITY`

On the end of each month i want to copy the sale of whole month to Table 3, so i use following query to transfer the record from Table 1 to Table 3.

```
INSERT INTO ANNUALSALE (MONTH, PRODUCTID, QUANTITY) 
SELECT 
  PRODUCTID,
  SUM(QUANTITY) 
FROM NETSALE 

WHERE 
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM INVOICEDATE) = 'thisMonth' 
AND  
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM INVOICEDATE) = 'thisYear'
GROUP BY(PRODUCTID)
```

Now i am facing difficulty in transferring the sale record from Table 2 to Table 3. i select all records from table 2 just like above with help of this query below having problem in its starting part marked in **. record should be inserted in such a way that if productID with this month is already exist then just update quantity otherwise insert a default.

```
**INSERT INTO ANNUALSALE (MONTH, PRODUCTID, QUANTITY)
**SELECT 
  PRODUCTID,
  SUM(QUANTITY)
FROM BALANCESALE
WHERE 
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM INVOICEDATE) = 'thisMonth' 
AND  
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM INVOICEDATE) = 'thisYear'
GROUP BY(PRODUCTID)
```

Comment: your post mentions h2, but it is also tagged mysql. what database are you really using?

Comment: @HaleemurAli I am using H2 i removed i removed mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have a unique key on month, productId, then mySQL will trigger an error if the record already exists, and you can use the 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' trigger.

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

I'm not sure if you can do it for multiple records at once. You'll probably need to do the select first, and then iterate over the result to do the insert with update one record at a time.

Comment: this would work for multiple records as well in mysql, but it is unclear if the OP is using mysql or h2.